# How do I reverse a list of commits in git?

Tags: git, version-control

I have a source tree with git and I need to reverse all my changes that I have done since September, I know the id of the commit, and I can also generate a list of commits that I want to revert with git rev-list, the question is how do I feed that list to git so that it uncommits all of them?

Or if there is a better way to do this I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to destroy all changes since a given commit, you can reset the branch you are working on (for example master) to the commit. What `git reset <commit>` does is that it moves your `HEAD` to the given commit. The following commits get discarded.

```
A---B---C---D-master
```

then

```
git reset --hard <SHA1-of-B>
```

gives you:

```
A---B-master
```

`--hard` is for discarding your recent changes from the index and your local files.

If you have multiple branches, this might get a bit more complicated, but you get the idea.

Note that the discarded commits may be recoverable with `git reflog`, but you won't be likely to see them if you're not trying to. Eventually, the discarded commits will disappear for good, especially if you're using `git gc` now and then.